# Editable combobox expressionDark theme bug

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, themes

I am using the ExpressionDark theme for the WPF application i'm developing.
However, I noticed a rather annoying bug when using an editable combobox.

As shown in the screenshot bellow, when I type a text that is longer than the control's width,  the content goes out of the combobox:

[image]

I tried with the default windows theme, and this bug is not present, so my guess is that there is a problem with the ExpressionDark theme.

I've explored the theme XAML for a while, but I couldn't find the source of the problem so far.

Maybe some of you already came across that problem and/or have an idea on how to fix this?

Many thanks!

P.S.: Is use the ExpressionDark theme that can be found on codeplex: http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found the problem. It was indeed a bug in the ExpressionDarkTheme. Here's the solution if anyone else run into this problem.

In the ExpressionDark.xaml file, search for the ControlTemplate named "ComboBoxTextBox". The goal is to put a scroll viewer in there so that the content can scroll horizontally.

Just replace the line

```
<Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
```

with

```
<Border Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollViewer}" />
</Border>
```

Voilà! Problem solved.